# How to post a data with an array field in react request?

Tags: django, reactjs, request, requestjs

So I'm using request from https://github.com/request/request#forms. In tsx file, I'm passing 
`id: id, text: string, array: number[]`.

```
post(
    {json: true, url: '...', form: {id: id, text: text, array: array}},
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (response.statusCode === 400) {
        dispatch(errStep(body['text']));
      } else {
        dispatch(addStep(body));
      }
    }
  )
```

This is a post method with the body `{id: id, text: text, array: array}`. However, from Django, when I print the `request.data`, I receive `<QueryDict: {'text': ['hello'], 'id': ['12'], 'array[0]': ['51'], 'array[1]': ['52']}>`.
This way, I can't retrieve the array ['51', '52] by calling `request.data.getlist('array')`.

I would like my request.data to be in this format: `<QueryDict: {'text': ['hello'], 'id': ['12'], 'array': ['51', '52']}>` because [51, 52] is returned by calling `request.data.getlist('array')`.

Thanks!

Comment: You have clearly mention that getlist('array') gives [51, 52]. It's not that you want?

Comment: @RajaSimon the request data is not in [51,53] but instead [51] and [53] separately.

Comment: But the answer to your request "how do I retrieve the array" is `getlist('array')`. What else do you want?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No my question is how to post an array field. I know how to retrieve the array only when there's an array in the request.data['arra'] field.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I'm even more confused. You did post an array. And how would you retrieve an array if you didn't post one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did post an array but the request.data is in the form 'array[0]': ['51'] , 'array[1]': ['53'] instead of 'array': ['51', '52'].

Answer (score 0):

`qsStringifyOptions: {arrayFormat: 'repeat'}` as one of the options in post call will transform `'array[0]': ['51'] , 'array[1]': ['53']` to `'array': ['51', '52']`